# Android Layout - Weighting

Tags: android, android-layout

I have spent hours trying to work this out, and spent a long time looking through other answers.
I'm evidently missing something simple, but really have been trying.

I cut my code down to the very basics to find the problem.

A layout has a backround, the top half of which is nice graphics, below the top half I am hoping to have the buttons.
The background is on the top, first linearlayout ( vertical ).
Then, inside this, are two vertical linear layouts.

The top vertical layout, has a weight of 1.
The bottom vertical layout, has a weight of 1.

This means to me, that the top layout should take up HALF of the screen. The buttons then going in the second layout should be ok to take up the rest of the screen.
However, when I start adding to the second layout, it no longer takes up half of the screen, but starts taking up space on the top half.

All I want to do, is to add four imagebuttons to the bottom half of the screen, centralised horizontally.

here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="@drawable/menubackground"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <!--  Layout 1, the top half -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Layout 2, the bottom half, containing buttons -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:src="@drawable/playbtnimg" android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:src="@drawable/achievementsbtnimg" android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Those two buttons, are now starting to take up around 2/3rd of the vertical space. They should not be going into the top half of the screen.
I'm trying to use layouts in this way so it will work on different screen sizes.
I would like the images to scale to fit within their linear layout cell, and not be cut off at the top of sides.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `weightsum` attribute to your root element ie the parent `LinearLayout`

here is what it would look like

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:background="@drawable/menubackground"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:weightSum="2"
android:orientation="vertical">
```

same would be for the `LinearLayout` having buttons

This would help further you can read more in android documentation

Comment: I appreciate this help. I put the weightsum of 2 on the containing layout, and put a weight of 1 on the two layouts within it. It still does the same :(. I then also put a weight sum of 1 on the bottom layout containing the buttons, and a weight of 0.25 on the buttons, still, the buttons take up more than half.

Comment: Ok, so i've gone even more basic and pulled the hello linear layout file from android here:
http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-linearlayout.html

What I find is, when I put a background on the top LinearLayout, the top row of colours then takes up less than 50%. 

How can this be something to do with the background? I don't understand.

Comment: What I see is... if I set the background to just a colour, it's fine. As soon as I put a background image on... then suddenly it's not correct. Any ideas? I even made sure to scale my pictures to the sizes recommended by Android

Comment: It also changes depending on theme. On some themes, it looks ok, on others.. it doesn't. Hmmm.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this code where you are using ImageButtons as backgrounds.

```
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

Fixed a similar issue I was having.

Hope it works and happy coding.

Comment: I found the answer.
I had two problems.
1) I did not use the scale to scale the image buttons.
2) I tried it on my device, and then a friends device, with the settings which were showing in eclipses GUI, and found that it's different on the device as it is on eclipse. It seems it's not 100% accurate on there.

Thanks for all your suggestions, they helped guide me.